# Can not set variable into thymeleaf template

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have to send email with thymeleaf template inside but I recieve clear html code without needed parameter (link). Where is my mistake?

Method:

```
private void sendLetter(User user, String subject, String link, String templatePath, Locale locale) {
    Context ctx = new Context(locale);
    ctx.setVariables(Collections.singletonMap("link", link));
    String htmlContent = templateEngine.process(templatePath, ctx);
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    try {
        MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
        message.setTo(user.getEmail());
        message.setFrom(emailProperties.getFrom());
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(htmlContent, true);
    }
    catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
}
```

Themeleaf:

```
<a class="main_button" href="${link}">
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question - how is the private method called, how are the parameters, what is in the ${link} and what do you expect to get

Comment: @GabiM I want to get input link value in href, instead of ${link}

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan no, just html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `th:href` instead of `href`.

Change your code from

```html
<a class="main_button" href="${link}">
```

to

```html
<a class="main_button" th:href="${link}">
```